# Is it possible to get dependencies of a procedure defined within package?

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, dependencies, package

I am aware that I can use the table 'dba_dependencies' to view dependencies of all stored procedures packages, but what if I want to get the dependencies of a specific procedure defined within a package? To my knowledge I cant get this from dba_dependencies.

Comment: Have you looked at [PL/Scope](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/adfns/plscope.html)?

Comment: Ha, [duplicate comment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39246751/266304) as well as question.